# Django testdatabase is missing tables

Tags: python, django, sqlite, testing

I have run into a case of missing tables whilst running Django(1.3.x) tests which are using a backported version of live server from 1.4 Normal tests run fine but it looks like the live server tests are not connecting to the proper database? The test database is defined as:

```
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
DATABASES['default']['NAME'] = ':memory:'
DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS'] = {}
DATABASES['default']['TEST_NAME'] = ':memory:'
```

I put a a print statement in `django.db.backends.creation.create_test_db`:

```
    # We need to then do a flush to ensure that any data installed by
    # custom SQL has been removed. The only test data should come from
    # test fixtures, or autogenerated from post_syncdb triggers.
    # This has the side effect of loading initial data (which was
    # intentionally skipped in the syncdb).
    call_command('flush',
        verbosity=max(verbosity - 1, 0),
        interactive=False,
        database=self.connection.alias)

    print 'django_site' in self.connection.introspection.table_names()
```

Which prints out:

```
True
```

So we see our database has been set up correctly.  However on the first request, a context_processor tries to access the Site model:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
Site.objects.get(pk=1)
DatabaseError: Database...o_site',)
```

And listing all the tables, returns an empty list:

```
from django.db import connection
print connection.introspection.table_names()
```

---

```
[]
```

It's as if this connection isn't connecting to the same one as during the setup but

```
connection.settings_dict
{'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'TEST_MIRROR': None, 'NAME': ':memory:',
'TEST_CHARSET': None, 'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC', 'TEST_COLLATION': None, 'PORT': '',
'HOST': '', 'USER': '', 'TEST_NAME': ':memory:', 'PASSWORD': '', 'OPTIONS': {}}
```

looks right?

Comment: Just to check: do you have `south` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @alecxe nope, not using south here.